# JS Multidimensional Arrays - How to get the .push() function working correctly

Tags: javascript, arrays

The following code example is what i found [here](https://www.tutsmake.com/javascript-multidimensional-array-with-push-pop/) on the internet

```
arr[1].push('native', 'laravel');
```

with a description of

> Here we use the javascript array push method to add two new elements(items) to the inner sub-array.

which was exactly what i wanted to accomplish!

But when i tried it several times by my self it always went like this:

```js
let mainArr = [];

console.log("mainArr: ", mainArr);
// Working as expected: created an empty array

let emptyArr = [];

console.log("emptyArr: ", emptyArr);
// Working as expected: created an empty array

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

  mainArr.push(emptyArr);
}

console.log("mainArr: ", mainArr);
// Working as expected: pushed 3 times the "emptyArr" into "mainArr"

let newArr = [["X"], [90]];

  mainArr[0].push(newArr);
  
console.log("mainArr[0]: ", mainArr[0]);
console.log("mainArr[1]: ", mainArr[1]);
console.log("mainArr[2]: ", mainArr[2]);
// NOT working as expected: pushed "newArr" into every of the three arrays within the "mainArr" !!!
// How can I solve this?
```

Would love to hear some tips :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because arrays are objects in JS, ie non-primitive type of variables.

**Long explanation**

Javascript has 5 data types that are passed by value: Boolean, String, Number, null and undefined. These are called primitive types.

And it has 3 data types that are passed by reference: Array, Function, and Object. These are all technically Objects.

When you assign a non-primitive value to a variable what happens is that a reference of that value is assigned, not the actual value. Ie, that reference points to the object’s location in memory. The variables don’t actually contain the value.

**In your case**

When you push `emptyArr` 3 times you don't insert the value (ie. a **new** empty array) you insert the same memory reference of `emptyArr`. These 3 references point to the same location in memory that has that value of an empty array. Given that, now you insert `newArr` to the referenced value of the `mainArr[0]`, but the rest elements `mainArr[1]`, `mainArr[2]` are references that point to the same value as the one pointed by `mainArr[0]`.

Hope it makes sense.

Otherwise, You can refer here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/430958/4700560 or I also find this article very visually descriptive and helpful https://blog.penjee.com/passing-by-value-vs-by-reference-java-graphical

Comment: Thank you so much! I was searching for this answer for hours...